# Examples on how to render a template in emberjs v1.0.0-pre.4?

Tags: templates, ember.js

I am missing something very fundamental to being able to render templates in **emberjs**. I found a few examples online..

[github.com/elucid/ember-tunes](http://github.com/elucid/ember-tunes)

[github.com/emberjs/examples](http://github.com/emberjs/examples)

I'm still not able to get my stuff working. These are also using a previous version of emberjs.

[ember-yii.sk.hj.cx/site/app](http://ember-yii.sk.hj.cx/site/app) seemed promising as well but, I was *still* not able to get my stuff working.

Does anyone know of examples specific to **v1.0.0-pre.4** ?

I'm trying to render a header, body, and footer as separate outlets. Here is the body of app.html:

```
<div id="main">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app">
        <header>
            {{outlet header}}
        </header>
        <section>
            {{outlet body}}
        </section>
        <footer>
            {{outlet footer}}
        </footer>
    </script>
</div>
```

What I'm not understanding is how to render templates within the 3 {{outlet}} placeholders.

I watched various EmberJS "tutorials", read the documentation. This is why I believe I'm missing something very fundamental.

Any help, guidance, or direction to helpful examples will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@akshayrawat has provided an absolute gold mine at: https://gist.github.com/akshayrawat/4701510    This is literally a list of 1.0.0-pre4 EmberJS resources.

@trek, one of the core EmberJS contributors created his own version of the Todos app at: https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences
I found this particularly useful when I was trying to figure out how to use multiple {{outlet}} placeholders.

Ps: The peepcode screencast on EmberJS costs 12 USD.. but it is really good and based on Embe 1.0.0-pre4

Comment: Thank you so much. The information you provided helped me fix the issue.